# Broken UTF-8 Encoding in Jar Output

Tags: java, encoding, cmd, utf-8, jar

I'm having problems with UTF-8 encoding when running jars from cmd. 
When running the project from IntelliJIdea I don't have any problems, the characters are shown and are outputted correctly.

To provide an example; I've used some of the suggested solutions from similar problems at here, stackoverflow, which I'll list.

```
public static String convertToUTF8(String s) {
        String out = null;
        try {
            out = new String(s.getBytes("UTF-8"), "ISO-8859-1");
        } catch (java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            return null;
        }
        return out;
    }

    System.out.println(Charset.defaultCharset());
    String test = "written in utf-8İİiiŞŞŞĞĞÜĞĞğ";
    System.out.println(test);
    System.out.println(convertToUTF8(test));
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new File("hello.txt"), "UTF-8");
    out.print("written in utf-8İİiiŞŞŞĞĞÜĞĞğ");
    out.close();
```

The outputs are as follows;

**Run from IntelliJIdea:**

- Console output:

  ```
  UTF-8
  written in utf-8İİiiŞŞŞĞĞÜĞĞğ
  written in utf-8Ä°Ä°iiÅÅÅÄÄÃÄÄÄ
  ```
- hello.txt: written in utf-8İİiiŞŞŞĞĞÜĞĞğ

**Run from cmd, using jar**

- Console output:

  ```
  windows-1252
  written in utf-8Ä°Ä°iiÅ?Å?Å?Ä?Ä???Ä?Ä?Ä?
  written in utf-8???°???°ii??Å???Å???Å???Å???Å???Å???Å???Å???Å?
  ```
- hello.txt: written in utf-8Ä°Ä°iiÅžÅžÅžÄžÄžÃœÄžÄžÄŸ

Other solutions that I've checked;

- Adding `-Dfile.encoding=utf-8` on cmd run, `java -Dfile.encoding=utf-8 -jar file.jar`: Changes nothing
- Using Ubuntu's terminal: the first line is UTF-8, but the rest is same as the cmd output.
- Running `chcp 65001` to change code page to UTF-8: while the visible output is fixed, hello.txt stays the same.
- Using powershell: Changes nothing.

What I want to achieve is getting correct encoding handling while running jar files from cmd since I plan to use the jar as a background worker which will handle a lot of UTF-8 encoded characters.

**Update:**
After replacing UTF-8 chars with unicode escape char equivalents; like ç to `\u011f`, the code runs as expected.
The thing that bothers me is, while I can do the string replace function like replace("ç", '\u011f') and the jar runs smoothly, why doesn't the system handle it correctly when outputting? If the system understands the char ç at runtime, why do I get Ä characters in output?

Comment: Update your question with the source of method `convertToUTF8()`. Also, since you are providing information from other SO questions, it would be helpful to link to them.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I'm adding the source method right away! @skomisa

Comment: Check your console font.

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of minor issues that should be simple to resolve (on Windows at least):

1. When creating the `String` in method `convertToUTF8()`, don't use the charset **ISO-8859-1**. It does not support Turkish characters, which explains why `convertToUTF8()` does not return the expected `String` value. To fix, simply use `UTF-8` instead:

   `out = new String(s.getBytes("UTF-8"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8.displayName());`
2. When running from the command line you need to use **-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8** for **file.encoding**. I notice that your setting is **-Dfile.encoding=utf-8**, so you might try changing **utf-8** to upper case. Since **windows-1252** is being shown as the `defaultCharset()` it looks like your value of **utf-8** is being ignored.

This code works for me, where the only significant change from yours is the assignment of `out` in method `convertToUTF8()`:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, UnsupportedEncodingException {

        System.out.println(Charset.defaultCharset());
        String test = "written in utf-8İİiiŞŞŞĞĞÜĞĞğ";
        System.out.println(test);
        System.out.println(convertToUTF8(test));
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new File("hello.txt"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8.displayName());
        out.print("written in utf-8İİiiŞŞŞĞĞÜĞĞğ");
        out.close();
    }

    public static String convertToUTF8(String s) {
        String out = null;
        try {
            out = new String(s.getBytes("UTF-8"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8.displayName());
        } catch (java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            return null;
        }
        return out;
    }
}
```

This is the output when running within Intellij IDEA:

```
C:\Java\openJDK\jdk-11.0.2\bin\java.exe -javaagent:C:\Users\johndoe\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Toolbox\apps\IDEA-U\ch-0\191.5109.14\lib\idea_rt.jar=60362:C:\Users\johndoe\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Toolbox\apps\IDEA-U\ch-0\191.5109.14\bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath C:\Users\johndoe\IdeaProjects\TurkishChars\out\production\TurkishChars Main
UTF-8
written in utf-8İİiiŞŞŞĞĞÜĞĞğ
written in utf-8İİiiŞŞŞĞĞÜĞĞğ

Process finished with exit code 0
```

And this is the console output when running from the command line:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17763.316]
(c) 2018 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\johndoe>chcp 65001
Active code page: 65001

C:\Users\johndoe>C:\Java\openJDK\jdk-11.0.2\bin\java.exe -javaagent:C:\Users\johndoe\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Toolbox\apps\IDEA-U\ch-0\191.5109.14\lib\idea_rt.jar=60362:C:\Users\johndoe\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Toolbox\apps\IDEA-U\ch-0\191.5109.14\bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath C:\Users\johndoe\IdeaProjects\TurkishChars\out\production\TurkishChars Main
UTF-8
written in utf-8İİiiŞŞŞĞĞÜĞĞğ
written in utf-8İİiiŞŞŞĞĞÜĞĞğ

C:\Users\johndoe>cd C:\Users\johndoe\IdeaProjects\TurkishChars

C:\Users\johndoe\IdeaProjects\TurkishChars>type hello.txt
written in utf-8İİiiŞŞŞĞĞÜĞĞğ
C:\Users\johndoe\IdeaProjects\TurkishChars>
```

[image: TurkishChars]

---

**Update:**

The suggestion from @Noodles to check your font is a good one. Try pasting your test text directly into the **Command Prompt** window to verify that it is rendered correctly (using ***echo written in utf-8İİiiŞŞŞĞĞÜĞĞğ***). If not, change the font. **Courier New** works for me:

[image: echoText]